# How can I, in Sass, target a specific child based on which parent it has, then use it inside media queries?

Tags: html, css, sass, responsive-images

I am trying to produce a mixin that should target a parent, inside a media query, that is nested inside an @at-root:

```html
<header> <!-- Should be targeted -->
    <img class="responsive" src="./some/file.jpg" alt="#" />
</header>

<div> <!-- Should be left alone -->
    <img class="responsive" src="./some/file.jpg" alt="#" />
</div>
```

Here is what i've got:

```css
@mixin media { 
    /* arcane magic not important here. */
}

@mixin image-specification() {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    @at-root #{&}.responsive {
        max-height:100%;
        max-width: 100%;
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
        background-size: contain;
        background-position:center;
        @include media("<=desktop") {
            @at-root header#{&} {
                max-width: 640px;
                max-height: 360px;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This does not seem to work, and I am a bit stuck here. Maybe this is the wrong approach, so any better solutions would be welcome.

Comment: Just curious if you are using the class `hero` for anything else? Why not just add styles for that class instead of trying to nest everything?

Comment: Also, since there's no such thing as a parent selector, how would expect this to be output to CSS? No matter what it would have to be output as `.hero { styles }`. There would be nothing to tie it to it's child.

Comment: I apologize, it should've been just tags( header, div etc). I would like to keep this short and expandable - which is why I try to go this route.

Comment: That doesn't matter. The issue is still there is no parent selector in CSS - you would still end up with `header { styles }`

Comment: Or you misunderstood my question? My goal was to be DRY and write as little code as possible. Not sure my answer managed to achieve that tho.

Comment: Perhaps. But this line from your question made it sound like you were trying to set styles for the parent `header` _"I am trying to produce a mixin that should target a parent"_. Based on your answer, you were trying to target the child element `img.respsonsive` if it was in a `header` element but wrap it in a media query. Either way, I'm glad you got it figured out!

Comment: My apologies, I can see where I was unclear. Thank you for your help in any case :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If using Sass 3.5, and you write the following code:

```
@mixin media($cond) {
    ...
}

@mixin imageDims($height: 100%, $width: 100%) {

    width: $height;
    height: $width;
    @at-root #{&}.responsive {
        max-width: $width;
        max-height: $height;
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
        background-size: contain;
        background-position:center;
        @include media("<=phone") {
            @at-root header > #{&} { // Verbose
                width: 640px;
                height:360px;
            }
        }
        @include media(">phone") {
            header > & { // less verbose
                width: 910.22px;
                height:512px;
            }
        }
        @include media(">=desktop") {
            header > & {
                width: 1280px;
                height:720px;
            }
        }
        @include media("retina2x") {
            header > & {
                width: 1706.67px;
                height:960px;
            }
        }
    }
}

img {
    @include imageDims();
  }
```

it compiles to:

````css
img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
img.responsive {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center;
}
@media (max-width: 320px) {
  header > img.responsive {
    width: 640px;
    height: 360px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 321px) {
  header > img.responsive {
    width: 910.22px;
    height: 512px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1024px) {
  header > img.responsive {
    width: 1280px;
    height: 720px;
  }
}
@media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), (min-resolution: 192dpi) {
  header > img.responsive {
    width: 1706.67px;
    height: 960px;
  }
}```

From where I stand, this makes writing sass a whole lot easier moving forward
````